# Show predefined plots in a shiny app with buttons

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to make a small Shiny app with radio buttons used to select a plot (predefined in the code) and show it. This is what I have:

```
# The plots called "Plot1" etc. are predefined in the environment.

Interface <- {
  fluidPage(
    sidebarPanel(
      radioButtons(inputId = "Question",
                   label = "Plots",
                   choices = c("A" = "Plot1", 
                               "B" = "Plot2", 
                               "C" = "Plot3"),
                   selected = "Plot1")),
    mainPanel(uiOutput('ui_plot'))
  )
}

Server <- function(input, output){
   output$barplot <- renderPlotly({   
    if (input == "A") return(Plot1)
    else if (input == "B") return(Plot2)
    else if (input == "C") return(Plot3)  
    })
}

 shinyApp(ui = Interface, server = Server)
```

But this is not working. I've tried replacing `return()` with `renderPlot()` but it doesn't change anything.

I'm sorry this is probably a very silly question/mistake, but it's my first time using Shiny! Thanks everyone!

Comment: Why are you using `uiOutput('ui_plot')`? Replace with `plotlyOutput("barplot")`.

Comment: I had tried as well, but received this error: `Error in pngfun: invalid quartz() device size`... With `plotOutput()`, on the other hand, it does not show an error message but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of errors in your code.

*In the interface:* replace `uiOutput('ui_plot')` with `plotlyOutput("barplot")`.

*In the server:*

- replace `input` with `input$Questions`
- replace `"A"` with `"Plot1"`, etc.

That is:

```
output$barplot <- renderPlotly({   
    if (input$Questions == "Plot1") return(Plot1)
    else if (input$Questions == "Plot2") return(Plot2)
    else if (input$Questions == "Plot3") return(Plot3)
})
```

Comment: Thanks! It finally worked with these suggestions, but only using `plotOutput()` in the UI and `renderPlot()` in the Server, instead of using the corresponding `plotly` functions. With  `plotlyOutput()` and `renderPlotly()` it still gave a white page.